# Symbol mathematics special in R

Tags: r, symbols

I want to find a list of symbols specials in R, for exemple:

```
\042 
\044
\136
\305
\341
```

Where is it, please?

Acctualy, i want find the code of symbol ∈ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with R, but [this website](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) helps me with escape symbols. Your posted character, ∈, is \u2208 .

Comment: Thanks. or https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/CM/AdobeSym.html